# How to change colors of Pie Chart slices in MVC(Razor HTML)?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have looked at similar posts on stack overflow. I think what I'm trying to do is different from older posts.

I want to change the colors of my pie chart slices. Is there a color item to add to '.AddSeries'

```
@{
        // Create Chart
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 500, height: 300)

        // Pass Y data from Model (String Array)
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Pie",        
            name: "OEE",
            xValue: new[] { "ON", "OFF" },
            yValues: Model)

        .Write();
    }
```

Comment: Never used it before, but would this documentation help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart#styling-a-chart

Comment: Check this post.  You have to use points in the data for the series...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450663/change-color-of-bars-depending-on-value-in-highchart-bar-chart-with-mvc3

Comment: I solved this by using a xml string like - string MyCustom =  "<Chart Palette=\"None\" PaletteCustomColors = \"50,205,50; 255,0,0;\"> </Chart>" ; Does anyone know how to set a font style in the above xml string? I have tried various things already but none of them work.